# SharePoint 2019 Crawl Error: The first attempt to crawl this object failed. (Failed to retieve blob from URI...)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-search, sharepoint-2019

I am working with a SharePoint 2019 farm with multiple servers. The search application and all its components are provided on a dedicated search server. It is working correctly but when I start the crawler it always shows up this error message:

The first attempt to crawl this object failed. Another attempt is being made. ( Failed to retieve blob from URI \SERVERNAME\gthrsvc_b120845e-7f97-4c51-b24b-db6e1bea42d7-crawl-0\2c\0x2c.docx.; ; SearchID = FDB56C58-8BF1-405B-8F65-E6346133549A )

The crawler service account got full read permissions.

I already tried the solutions described by these articles:

- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/1a7e3467-e824-47b9-9129-a59bb665d1e6/many-errors-in-the-crawl-log-sp-2013?forum=sharepointsearch
- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/95f57fb3-6b14-479b-8f6e-d39f1f634343/failed-to-retrieve-blob-from-uri-error-in-sharepoint-2013-search-crawl-logs?forum=sharepointsearch

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

In this case it was a very basic solution. File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks was not enabled on the network adapter. After enabling the adapter option everything works properly.